# Airflow Worker - KeyError: u'No such transport: ampq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, airflow, kombu

I am new to airflow and trying to setup airflow cluster. The issue is when I try starting airflow worker I get error

> KeyError: u'No such transport: ampq.  Did you mean amqp?'.

Versions:

- apache-airflow==1.10.6
- celery==4.0.2
- kombu==4.0.2

My rabbitmq instance is up and running. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my configuration in airflow.cfg file.

```
broker_url = ampq://guest:***@192.168.43.130:5672//

result_backend = db+postgresql://postgres:***@192.168.43.130:5432/postgres
```

Comment: Update: If i try downgrading Celery & Kombu versions .. airflow worker starts up but then airflow scheduler on server starts giving error - "airflow celery AttributeError - Disabled backed object has no attribute 'get_task_meta_for". Although I added result_backed.

Comment: just typo, 'ampq' -> 'amqp'

Comment: Thanks !! this was a pretty stupid mistake I did.